# Implementing Trie (or similar data structure) on spark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working as an intern, I've been tasked with implementing a fast searching algorithm for phone numbers on their spark cluster, using `tries` (prefix tree), and performing operations such as inner join on several such tries

I managed to create get it working for about 5 million numbers (2 tries, with 2.5 mllion numbers in each)
I've been tasked to scale it up to 10-20 million. though if I try to go above that I get `Java.outofmemory` error

Right Now my approach is this
My code, 
- create a dataframe of phonenumbers from the spark database, 
- loads 2.5 million numbers into memory (memory of the JVM) in a python list, using collect()
- converts that list into trie
- clear the list
- search the number_to_be_searched in the trie
- if found return true
- else load next 2.5 million numbers, and repeat step 3 and so on

```py
from collections import defaultdict


class Trie:
    # Implement a trie with insert, search.

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = defaultdict()

    def insert(self, word):
        current = self.root
        for letter in word:
            current = current.setdefault(letter, {})
        current.setdefault("_end")

    def search(self, word):
        current = self.root
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in current:
                return False
            current = current[letter]
        if "_end" in current:
            return True
        return False

# these are the inner join and merge functions

def ijoin_util(root1, root2, str):

    for k in root1:
        if k == '_end':
            ijoin_util.join.append(str)
            return
        found = root2.get(k)
        if found != None:
            ijoin_util(root1[k], found, str + k)


def inner_join(root1, root2):
    str = ""
    ijoin_util.join = []
    ijoin_util(root1.root, root2.root, str)
    return ijoin_util.join


def merge_util(root1, root2):
    for k in root1:
        found = root2.get(k)
        if found != None:
            merge_util(root1[k], found)
        else:
            root2.update({k: root1[k]})
            return root2

def merge(root1, root2):
    merge_util(root1.root, root2.root)
```

I know this is a really bad implementation for the problem, and I want to know if I can implement this in a way where I dont have to store the trie in the memory, (I mean like if I store it as RDD of nested maps), or any other approach which might help me scale it further

Comment: could you provide with your spark code? how do you  make use spark with class Trie?